# Stochastic Search to lambda expression

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, artificial-intelligence, stochastic

Thanks for all your help and sharing.

My question is in regards of the Stochastic Search. This technique is used to do approximations of data through a defined amount of cicles over a, an in general, mathematical calculation. Please see following code, I tried to reduce it to its minimum. My expectation is to have this code setup as a lambda expression, the for loop, I would like to have the best performance of it. I have some intents but I'm not sure if I got the most of it.

```
package stochasticsearch;
import java.util.Random;
public class StochasticSearch {
    public static double f(double x) {
        return -(x - 1) * (x - 1) + 2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        double startPointX = 0;
        double max = f(startPointX);
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            double index = 2 * random.nextDouble();
            if (f(index) > max) {
                max = f(index);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - begin));
        System.out.println("Maximum value y=f(x) is " + max);
    }
}
```

Thanks, have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code completes in a little under 23 seconds on my system, and I was able to modify it so that it takes under 2 seconds.  Here's what I found:

- You're using `Random` when you could be using `ThreadLocalRandom` instead; this switch results in a relatively-large speedup.
- You're calculating `f(index)` twice inside your for-loop in certain cases when it should only be computed once per iteration.
- Because you're iterating over a large range of values, you could utilize a parallel stream instead; this results in a relatively-large speedup as well.
- You're adding `2` to every result in `f`, so it's better to add it a single time once `max` has been calculated.

  ```
  public static double f(double x) {
      double y = x - 1;
      return -y * y;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      final ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

      long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

      double max = IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000_000)
                            .parallel()
                            .mapToDouble(i -> f(random.nextDouble() * 2))
                            .max()
                            .orElse(f(0)) + 2;

      System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - begin));
      System.out.println("Maximum value y=f(x) is " + max);
  }
  ```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the quick turnaround. You have my vote :)